# Numpy ValueError: scale < 0

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm a newbie in python and running this code

The code defines the fonction C(u), and then Cminus(u) 
After that I'm using the fonction minimize from SCIPY with the methode LBFGS-B which gives me ustar to finally get Xstar=(-1/(2*sigma))*Cminus(ustar)

At some point I have the error  scale<0

I can't figure out where is my error

Any idea ?

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.linalg.lapack import dsyevr
from scipy.linalg import eig
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigsh
import statistics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

def Initialisation(N,sigmaini):
    global n,A,m,B,b,p,sigma
    sigma=sigmaini
    n = N
    p=n
    W = np.random.random(size=(n,n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            W[j][i] = W[i][j]

    #for i in range(n):
        #W[i][i] = 0

    A = -W
    m = n+1
    B = []
    for i in range(n):
        Bi = np.zeros ((n,n))
        for k in range(n):
            for l in range(n):
                if k == l and k == i:
                    Bi[k][l] = 1
                else:
                    Bi[k][l] = 0
        B.append(Bi)
    b = np.zeros((m))
    for i in range(m):
        if i == n:
            b[i] = 0
        else :
            b[i]=1

    e = np.zeros((n))
    for i in range(n):
        e[i]=1

    Bm = e * e.transpose()
    B.append(Bm)

def C(u):        
    c=np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in range (m):
        c=c+u[i]*B[i]
    c=c+A
    return c

def Cminus(u):
    evals, evecs = eigsh(C(u))
    valpneg=evals[evals<0]
    vecpneg=evecs[:,evals<0]
    vecpneg.shape[0]#ligne
    vecpneg.shape[1]#colonnes=#les valeurs propres
    cminus =np.zeros((n,n))

    for i in np.arange(0,vecpneg.shape[1]):
        cminus=cminus+valpneg[i]*np.dot(vecpneg[:,i].reshape(n,1), vecpneg[:,i].T.reshape(1,n))
    return cminus

def calcul_grad(u):
    gradd = []
    for i in range (m):
        gi = -1/(2*sigma)*np.sum(Cminus(u)*B[i])-b[i]
        gradd.append(gi)
    return gradd


def Objective(u):
    o = (1/(4*sigma))*np.sum(Cminus(u)*Cminus(u))+np.dot(u,b)
    return o


def Minimize():
    u_init = np.zeros((m))
    sol = minimize(Objective, u_init,method='L-BFGS-B', jac=None, hess=None, hessp=None, bounds=None)
    ustraSD4 = sol.x
    return ustraSD4

def Sdcut_sol():
    XstarSdcut = (1/(2*sigma))*-Cminus(Minimize())
    return XstarSdcut

def Rounding_inter():
    Y=Sdcut_sol()
    zstar = np.random.normal(0,Y,n)
    xstar = np.sign(zstar-statistics.median(zstar)) 
    return xstar
```

Comment: *"At some point I have the error scale<0"*  Whenever you report an error in a stackoverflow question, include the complete error message (i.e. the complete traceback) in the question.  There is useful information in there.

Comment: In the function `Rounding_inter`, check the value of `Y` before the line `zstar = np.random.normal(0,Y,n)`.  The second argument to `np.random.normal` is `scale`, and it must not be negative.